# directional derivatives at (0,0) vanish

Tags: analysis, partial-derivative

Is the statment that all directional dervatives vanish at (0,0) really true, it seems to me the last equation states the opposite.

[image]

The example is from:
Mathematical Analysis: An Introduction to Functions of Several Variables
Mariano Giaquinta,Giuseppe Modica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. The partial derivatives, not all directional derivatives, vanish at $(0,0)$. There are other examples of continuous functions with all directional derivatives at $(0,0)$ equal to $0$ which nevertheless fail to be differentiable there.